# For each distinct PK I have a mixture of TRUE/FALSE

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

If a PK has one YES value, I want all the other values to be YES. I am thinking going a CTE route that I join back in but was wondering if there is an easier way!

```
A table below

| CUSTOMER_ID | CONTRACT_ID | ACTIVE |

  1182102192         1          N
  1182102192         2          N
  1182102192         3          N
  1182102192         4          Y
  1182102192         5          N
```

I am trying to get my table to look like this if only one Y is in the table above.:

```
| CUSTOMER_ID | CONTRACT_ID | ACTIVE |

  1182102192         1          Y
  1182102192         2          Y
  1182102192         3          Y
  1182102192         4          Y
  1182102192         5          Y
```

Comment: Self-join will do the trick like you say. But begs the question: why isn't `ACTIVE` a column on the `CUSTOMER` table instead

Comment: @Charlieface I believe this is how we're trying to set "ACTIVE" on the CUSTOMER table. Totally agree ACTIVE needs to be mastered by the customer object. We're using logic from the CONTRACTS table to tell if a CUSTOMER is "ACTIVE"

Comment: Or what about a window function `select *, IsActive = isnull(min(case when ACTIVE = 'Y' then ACTIVE end) over (partition by CUSTOMER_ID), 'N') from Table`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *strongly* recommend window functions if you just want a `SELECT`:

```
select ct.*,
       max(active) over (partition by customer_id) as imputed_active
from customertable ct;
```

Comment: This query will perform far better than the "Quick and Dirty" approach.  Gordon gets my vote.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty...

```
;WITH ActiveCustomers
AS (
    SELECT Customer_ID
    FROM CustomerTable
    WHERE Active='Y'
    )
SELECT C.Customer_ID, C.Contract_ID, CASE WHEN A.Customer_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS [Active]
from CustomerTable C
LEFT JOIN ActiveCustomers A
    ON C.Customer_ID = A.Customer_ID
```